# View a rdoc file in a ruby gem

Tags: ruby, rdoc

I want to read some of the documentation for the `rb-gsl` [gem](https://github.com/SciRuby/rb-gsl). For example the [rdoc file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SciRuby/rb-gsl/master/rdoc/multimin.rdoc) for the multimin class. How do I view this file in a browser and follow the links that are in the file (which appear to refer to other rdoc files in the same repository).

Comment: Isn't this good? https://rdoc.info/github/SciRuby/rb-gsl/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two options I know of to view rdoc documentation for gems:

1. Using the online documentation - for example: https://rdoc.info/github/SciRuby/rb-gsl/
2. Using [Yard](https://yardoc.org/)

With Yard, you can do many things, including running a local server to show the documentation for all the installed gems.

```
$ gem install yard
$ yard server --gems --port 3000
```

Then, visit http://localhost:3000 to see a list of gems, each with its full documentation.

Comment: I had a look at the rdoc.info site, clicking the links, I cannot find the multimin description. I also tried looking for ```FdfMinimizer``` which is a class described in the mutlimin rdoc file but no luck.  If I look for it on the site search box nothing comes up. Are you able to show me the link for it?  I did  ```gem install yard``` and it seems to install yard-0.9.26 bult when I try to start the server or even type ```yard --help``` I get ```-bash: yard: command not found```

Comment: I believe the rdeoc folder is used for generating some docs site. You might be able to view it with yard locally. I found a rendering of it here: https://blackwinter.github.io/rb-gsl/rdoc/multimin_rdoc.html -as for yard not working, log out and log in should fix it. If not, you have a problem in your ruby setup.

Comment: Thanks for finding the blackwinter site.  Logging in and out fixed yard.But I am not seeing the multimin documentation, but there is something strange with my setup  or with rb-gsl/gsl. I will investigate and get back to you on this. In the meant time, you have answered my general question so I will accept and upvote your answer

Comment: It looks like rb-gsl has some sort of protocol converter between ruby and C to call the C functions without actually having an explicit ruby method, so it seems likely to me that the normal rdoc processes will not work.